# Turn off: \UseRawInputEncoding after specific text

Tags: formatting

Is it possible to turn off `\UseRawInputEncoding` after a specific line?

I had to put it in to display my code.

I tried to implement `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` after my "code block". 
But it only gives me this error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.See the LaTeX manual or
>   LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help....
>   \usepackage

Comment: From the definition of `\UseRawInputEncoding` it looks like it's effects are local to a scope, so if you use it inside a group it should revert after the group ends.

Comment: It's not clear why. A file can use only one encoding.

Comment: Do you _really_ have a file that starts using UTF-8 mid-file? (if you do need to change encodings you can use `\inputencoding{utf8}` you don't need `\usepackage` mid file, but that would be very very strange.

Comment: Maybe not mid-file, but certainly it would be reasonable for a job to involve input from a different file that uses a different encoding. I can imagine many applications of this, including re-use of files prepared years ago; e.g., for an updated edition of a textbook, or similar job.